# Reason for 200 upvote points limit?

Tags: discussion

What's the reason for the 200 upvote points a day limit? I had 8 upvotes yesterday which didn't earn me any points :-(

**edit**
OK, so I hit the cap for the 14th day in a row! Cost me a fortune in rep :-/. I propose to make it 300.

**edit 2**
Looks like 300 wouldn't be do either. Without cap I would have gotten 795 yesterday, so this silly cap cost me 580 in rep :-(

[image]

Comment: You're welcome to continue to ask questions like this on our individual site's meta, but many of the general questions are also answered on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  For instance, there are 76 questions in the [[daily-reputation-limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation+daily-reputation-limit)] tag, and [here's a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap) titled "What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?" which may answer your question.

Comment: @Kevin - OK, thanks. Must admit that I didn't have a look there.

Comment: Keep it up!  You're getting closer to the [Epic](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/badges/26/epic) and [Legendary](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/badges/27/legendary) badges.  You might be the first to get there!  You can see your progress at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/reputation (that page is the "raw data" view of your profile's [rep graph](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/2064/stevenvh?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph)).

Comment: @stevenvh: This is the system telling to you get a life ;-)  However, if you wrote good answers that people found helpful then it does seem a bit unfair to not get the credit just because they were lumped in time.

Comment: does it have to be all about 'rep points'? isn't helping people out its own reward? sorry if this comes across sounding a bit sour, but this sort of fixation on scoring, as if this were some kind of competitive game, is kind of off-putting.

Comment: @JustJeff - Yes, of course it about giving answers to others' questions, and people here who got to know me a bit will confirm that's what I want. But the rep is a kind of confirmation that I'm not just doing the right thing, but also that I'm doing it right.

Comment: @stevenvh - to balance my prior comment, not that you don't generate great content, you do. I really wasn't trying to personally take a shot at you, it's just an aspect of the stack exchange system that I find kind of disappointing.

Answer (score 4):

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/podcast-72/

> The daily reputation cap is partly there to encourage programmers to take a break. The goal isn’t to be on Stack Overflow, but to generally do things that make you a better programmer. While that certainly includes the fractional time slices of questions and answers that programmers so generously contribute, it also means doing your job, and writing code! To the extent that Stack Overflow itself becomes the goal, we are failing you.

And officially https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Beyond that consider that "hitting the jackpot" with one super popular post would potentially convert you from a 1 rep user to a 10,000 rep user in *one day*. I doubt that user would be familiar enough with our Q&A sites to know what to do with such earned privileges...

Comment: I've seen numbers like this 10 000 before, and it looks like SO in that sense is completely different from EE. Here a few very active users manage to get ~200 rep in one day sometimes, for maybe 3 or 4 answers. (My example for yesterday where I got 28 upvotes is an exception, I posted something like 7 answers or so.) That would be more or less the maximum, so you won't see a 10 000 flood on EE.

Comment: @Stevenvh, but I have published questions to other sites and see a large number of hits in moments with much increased voting and activity. You are right, 10,000 is not the issue now, but if you keep writing great answers soon enough it will be feasible.